# template function for object members and standard types

Tags: c++, templates, member

I essentially want to merge the two print functions below into a single function, if that is actually possible. That is, I want to have one template function that accepts just an ordinary type (int, float, std::string, etc) and an additional argument specifying a member.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct MyStruct{
  int a;
  int b;
  std::string c;

  MyStruct(int a_, int b_, std::string c_) : a(a_), b(b_), c(c_) {}
};

template <typename TObject, typename TMember>
void print(const TObject &object, TMember member){
  std::cout << object.*member << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void print(const T &val){
  std::cout << val << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  MyStruct s(50, 100, "this is a test\n");
  print(s, &MyStruct::a);
  print(s, &MyStruct::b);
  print(s, &MyStruct::c);

  print(s.a);
  print(s.b);
  print(s.c);
}
```

Perhaps there is some sort of template magic that can handle this.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't see where the failure is. Does this somehow *not* do what you intended? Both sets of `print` calls emit identical data on my rig, so perhaps also show us what you would *like* to work, but currently *does not* ?

Comment: The easiest solution against code duplication would be using `print(object.*member);` in the first print.

Comment: there is no failure.  I was simply wondering if it is possible to handle both situations with one template function.  Just exploring c++ templates for the moment and was interested in a solution to this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get it to work for primitive types, as pointers to members of primitive types are not allowed (GCC error here):

> error: creating pointer to member of non-class type 'int'

Still, after a lot of fumbling around, due to the compiler thinking I'm trying to get the member-pointer to point to a constructor (as if), I finally got it to work for class types (all the rest):

First, we need some struct where I know the first element, just to get a valid member-pointer pointing at the start of a struct:

```
struct a{char a;};
```

Next, we add a default for the template argument: A member-pointer which maps a `TObject` to a `TObject`:

```
template <typename TObject, typename TMember = TObject TObject::*>
```

Because we use a data member-pointer, the forced conversion is ok:

```
void print(const TObject &object, TMember member = (TMember)&a::a){
  std::cout << object.*member << std::endl;
}
```

Voila, our print function can not only use member-pointers, we can even omit them if we want to print the object itself.
Somehow, I cannot bring myself to call that a simplification though...

Comment: I also agree that it is not a simplification and not the elegant solution was imagining, but thank you very much for the reply.